# Problema con consultas en bases de datos relacionadas

Tags: base-de-datos, mysqli, codeigniter

Buenos días

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en la que uno 3 tablas y quiero poder listar las tareas asignadas a un usuario con sus correspondientes Tag, pero me **duplica las tareas que contienen más de un Tag**.

El código es el siguiente:

```
* task_asignation
id taskId asignedBy asignedTo state priority
1    1       6          6       1        1
2    2       6          6       1        1
3    3       1          2       1        1
4    4       2          3       1        1
5    5       6          1       1        1

* task
taskId title  createdBy editedBy
1     prueba1    6         6 
2     prueba2    6         6 
3     Prueba3    1         1
4     Prueba4    2         2 
5     Prueba5    6         6 

* task_tag
id taskId      name      createdBy
1    1       pruebas        6
2    2         test         6
3    3     pruebas/test     1
5    5      Software        6
6    5      hardware        6
```

Modelo:

```
public function getAsignedTasks($employeeId){
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('task_asignation')->join('task', 'taskId', 'INNER JOIN')->join('task_tag', 'taskId', 'LEFT JOIN')->where('asignedBy', $employeeId)->get();


    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query;
    }else{
        return array();
    }   
}
```

Controlador:

```
$tasksAsignedData   = $this->Mtasks->getAsignedTasks($data['employeeId']);
$data['tasksAsigned'] = $tasksAsignedData->result();
```

Vista:

```
 foreach ($tasksAsigned as $key => $value) {
              echo $value->title;
              echo $value->name;
}
```

Como resultado obtengo:

```
Tarea de prueba 1
pruebas

Tarea de prueba 2
test

Prueba 5
Software

Prueba 5
hardware
```

Comment: Hola! Mencionas que obtienes registros duplicados, pero de los resultados que obtienes, ¿Me podrías señalar cuales están duplicados?

Comment: Los resultados a los que me refiero son: Prueba 5 Software, Prueba 5 Hardware, esto debería aparecer Prueba5 Software Hardware

Comment: No se si estoy viendo mal pero Hardware y Software, ambos tienen taskId = 5, entonces te retornará esos valores.

Comment: Como bien dices ahí es donde está mi problema, no quiero que aparezca Prueba 5 dos veces sino que me aparezcan las dos Tag que le pertenecen.

Comment: Tendrías que agruparlos entonces para que aparezcan en una sola linea.

Comment: ¿y como los agrupo para que aparezcan así? No tengo mucha práctica con este tipo de consultas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder obtener los registros de Hardware y Software en una sola linea, tendrias que utilizar o un `SUBQUERY` o agruparlos y utilizar `GROUP_CONCAT`.

A continuación te presento unas guías:

```
SELECT t.title, GROUP_CONCAT(tt.name SEPARATOR ',') FROM task_asignation ta 
   INNER JOIN task t ON t.taskId = ta.taskId
    LEFT JOIN task_tag tt ON tt.taskId = ta.taskId
     GROUP BY t.title
```

o

```
SELECT ta.*,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tt.name SEPARATOR ',') FROM task_tag tt 
      WHERE tt.taskId = ta.taskId) tag_name
  FROM task_asignation ta 
 INNER JOIN task t ON t.taskId = ta.taskId
```

**NOTA**: Estos queries no los probe, pero es una idea de como los debes armar para obtener lo que necesitas.

Te envío el URL de referencia de la función [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Pues siguiendo tus consejos he creado la query así:
$query = $this->db->select( task.title, GROUP_CONCAT(task_tag.name SEPARATOR ',') FROM task_asignation INNER JOIN task ON task.taskId = task_asignation.taskId LEFT JOIN task_tag ON task_tag.taskId = task_asignation.taskId GROUP BY task.title)->get();
Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:
Message: syntax error, unexpected 'SEPARATOR' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: La respuesta era correcta, lo que me fallaba era la síntasis: 
SELECT task.*, employee.employeeImage,
        GROUP_CONCAT(be_task_tag.name SEPARATOR ',') as name,
        FROM task_asignation 
        LEFT JOIN task ON task.taskId = task_asignation.taskId 
        LEFT JOIN task_tag ON task_tag.taskId = task_asignation.taskId
        where task_asignation.asignedTo = $employeeId 
        GROUP BY task.title order by task.created
Gracias por la respuesta :)

Comment: Fue un placer haberte ayudado. Si es posible, me ayudas con un voto positivo a la respuesta.

Comment: Ya lo hice, aunque parece que no será visible hasta que no tenga 15 de reputación. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para evitar redundancia que es lo que te entiendo, debes usar GROUP BY al final, debes definir un parámetro que no quieres que se repita y agruparlos por eso, en tu caso el id de tarea, así no se repetirían esos registros; otra opción es jugar con LEFT JOIN y RIGHT JOIN para unir las tablas ya que dependiendo de cual uses el no traerá los datos repetidos de la tabla de la izquierda o derecha; y otra opción es usar DISTINCT para que no te traiga los repetidos.

con DISTINCT:

Select DISTINCT(idtarea), otros campos.....  from tabla1 join tabla2 join tabla3 on tabla.id = tabla2.id...... etc.

con GROUPBY:

Select idtarea, .....  from tabla1 join tabla2 join tabla3 on tabla.id = tabla2.id...... etc.  group by idtarea.

Comment: Añadiendo GROUPBY O DISTINCT. No da el resultado que espero, solo me muestra la primera tag de la tarea e ignora el resto.

Comment: entonces además usa AS para que solo te muestre los nombres concatenados select id, CONCAT_WS('  ', nombres) AS nombres from....... etc., esto genera una vista en la que te muestra solo los nombres sin que se repita el id.

Comment: obtengo el siguiente error:
    public function getAsignTasks($employeeId){
        $query = $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->select CONCAT_WS(' ', 'name') AS nombres
        ->from('task_tag')
        ->join('task', 'taskId', 'INNER JOIN')
        ->join('task_asignation', 'taskId', 'INNER JOIN')
        ->where('asignedTo', $employeeId)
        ->group_by('taskId')
        ->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query;
        }else{
            return array();
        }   
    }

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'CONCAT_WS' (T_STRING)